# Sed in file when docker-compose run -e called my env

Tags: docker, shell, sed, docker-compose

It's too difficult to explain what I need but I do my best.

In entrypoint.sh file I wrote these lines:

```
if [ ! -z "${BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals}" ]; then \
  sed -i \
  -e '/LoadModule .*mod_brotli.so/ s/^#*/#/'   \
  /config/default.conf
&& echo AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS $BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals  >> /config/default.conf
fi;
```

The default.conf file contains only this line:

```
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
```

then when I run this command :

```
docker-compose run -e BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals="text/plain" mycontainer
```

then here you go the default.conf:

```
LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so 
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/plain
```

**Uncommented** the first line as you see and added a line with **what I set** when I ran docker-compose run command {**BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals="text/plain"**})

Also -e BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals is optional (if user write then do what I said, if not default.conf has a one commented line)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals="text/plain"
replacement="AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS $BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals"
target_file="/config/default.conf"

if [ -n "${BROTLI_COMPRESS_Vals}" ]; then
    replacement="$(echo "$replacement" | sed 's/[][\\\/\.^$+*?(){}|]/\\&/g')"
    sed -i "0,/^#\(.*\)$/s//\1\n${replacement}/" "$target_file"
fi
```

```sh
$ cat config.txt
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
$ ./shell.sh
LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS text/plain
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
#LoadModule brotli_module modules/mod_brotli.so
```

Make sure to backup your file first.

Comment: That was awesome, also your script gives me an idea , Thank you <3